# Trigger function() on replaceWith() of HTML element

Tags: jquery

I am trying to trigger a function right after an HTML element is replaced; however, nothing is happening. I've read the jQuery documentation on the trigger() method, but I'm still unsure of how to use it. I just want to be able to synchronously fire the second function right after the replaceWith() method.

Here is my code:

```
$('#dry-wet-table').on("custom", function () {
                $(this).replaceWith('<table id="dry-wet-table"></table>');
            })

            $('#dry-wet-table').trigger("custom", function () {
                $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><th>" + dryDietVal + "</th><th>" + wetDietVal + "</th></tr>");
                $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><td>0</td><td>" + cansPerDay + "</td></tr>");

                for (var a = cansPerDay - 0.25; a >= 0; a -= 0.25) {

                    if ($('#species option:selected').text() == "Cat") {
                        $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><td>" + ((parseFloat($('#calories').val()) - (parseFloat($('#diet-select-wet-cat option:selected').val()) * a)) / parseFloat($('#diet-select-dry-cat option:selected').val())).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + a + "</td></tr>");
                        if (a == Infinity) {
                            a = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($('#species option:selected').text() == "Dog") {
                        $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><td>" + ((parseFloat($('#calories').val()) - (parseFloat($('#diet-select-wet-dog option:selected').val()) * a)) / parseFloat($('#diet-select-dry-dog option:selected').val())).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + a + "</td></tr>");
                        if (a == Infinity) {
                            a = 0;
                        }
                    }

                }
            })
```

*** UPDATE ***

I've found a better way to do fire these two functions synchronously and I've answered my own question below.

Basically, instead of using the trigger() method alone, you can use the jQuery.when() API to run a function right after your custom event is done being triggered.

Comment: `$('#dry-wet-table').trigger("custom");` A trigger does not have function call: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Comment: I've read the documentation, however it doesn't explain how to use the trigger() function very well.

Comment: Why are you splitting the functions? If you want to do stuff when triggering, add the rest of the code to the custom function.

Comment: Simple trigger https://jsfiddle.net/sobb1r1b/#&togetherjs=k8p9bfV6ko

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a better way to fire these two events synchronously. Instead of using the trigger() method alone, you can use the jQuery.when() API to run a function right after your custom event is done being triggered.

```
$('#dry-wet-table').on("custom", function () {
                $(this).replaceWith('<table id="dry-wet-table"></table>');
            })

$('#dry-wet-table').trigger("custom");

$.when($(this).trigger('custom')).done(function () {

         $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><th>" + dryDietVal + "</th><th>" + wetDietVal + "</th></tr>");
         $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><td>0</td><td>" + cansPerDay + "</td></tr>");

          for (var a = cansPerDay - 0.25; a >= 0; a -= 0.25) {

                    if ($('#species option:selected').text() == "Cat") {
                        $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><td>" + ((parseFloat($('#calories').val()) - (parseFloat($('#diet-select-wet-cat option:selected').val()) * a)) / parseFloat($('#diet-select-dry-cat option:selected').val())).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + a + "</td></tr>");
                        if (a == Infinity) {
                            a = 0;
                        }
                    }
                    else if ($('#species option:selected').text() == "Dog") {
                        $('#dry-wet-table').append("<tr><td>" + ((parseFloat($('#calories').val()) - (parseFloat($('#diet-select-wet-dog option:selected').val()) * a)) / parseFloat($('#diet-select-dry-dog option:selected').val())).toFixed(2) + "</td><td>" + a + "</td></tr>");
                        if (a == Infinity) {
                            a = 0;
                        }
                    }

             }

 });
```

Answer (score 1):

A sample usage:

```js
$(function () {
  $('#btn').on('custom', function(e) {
    $('<p>Custom event handled.</p>').insertAfter(this);
  });

  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $(this).trigger('custom');
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Click Me</button>
```

Comment: This does not seem to answer the question.

Answer (score 1):

also call a trigger with parameters

```
$('#dry-wet-table').trigger("custom",[5,10,20]);
```